# Android Thread explanation?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Sorry everyone this has been asked a few times but I just do not understand any of the answers because most are about timed UI updates. So I have a backgroundTasks thread that is called when my app first starts(Does network connections so..I think that's how you do it?)

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        String data[][];
        int arrayPosition = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        runBackgroundTask();

    }
```

Here is my thread..

```
 public void runBackgroundTask(){
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    data = pullSchedule(data);
                    updateUI(data,arrayPosition);
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

All it does is call a method pullSchedule which updates a 2D array with a webcrawler. So my problem comes when I call the updateUI method which is also used by two buttons to cycle through the array data which work perfectly fine. It's just when the thread first runs if I try to update the UI I get an error.

```
 public void upDateUI(String data[][], int arrayPosition){
        TextView gameTime =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        //more but deleted to save space :)
    }
```

I have researched why I cannot update the UI from the background thread but I don't understand how to fix this? I thought about putting that entire method into the `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()`but then I believe my data and arrayPosition have to be declared final because of an inner class..First Android app just lost. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you taken a look at AsyncTask?  It has a callback method called onPostExecute which lets you update the UI after your background process has finished.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: you can create `Handler` in UI thread and use `Handler.post( Runnable r )` inside your thread. But the best way is using AsyncTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use asyntask for this from which you can update ui

```
public myAsyn extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
   @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
         data = pullSchedule(data);
               return null;     
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           updateUI(data,arrayPosition);
        }
}
```

`doInBackground` runs on seperate thread whereas `onPostExecute` runs on Ui thread therefore you can update UI from there.

Comment: Thanks I'll have to look into AsycTask

Comment: I have it set up like this and it's saying I'm not using onPost Execute? Sorry not sure how to format the comment! @wqrahd

`public class myAsyn extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        data = pullSchedule();
        return null;
    }


        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        upDateUI(data,arrayPosition);
    }
    }`

Comment: just copy and paste my answer

Comment: Inside mainActvity? Few errors came up with public myAsyn extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>, String and null being an incompatible return type, and @Override for onPostExecute does not override the method superclass

Comment: it depends on you where you are defining but it can be inside mainactivity. post your whole code if error doesnot resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. The reason your app is crashing is because you are attempting to update a UI element off of the UI thread. To avoid this, you can either do as RichS suggested, and use an AsyncTask which will execute `onPostExecute()` on the UI thread, or surround your `updateUI()` call in your background thread with `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...`.